# How do I delete multiple records in my database

Tags: php, mysql

I wanna create a button which deletes all the records that needs to be deleted. I have three tables in my database person, address and cv... address_id has a relation with person_address in person table and cv_id has a relation with person_cv in person table. When the delete button is pressed everything connected to the person should be deleted. I tried lots of things like:

```
 echo "<td><a href='delete.php?id=<?" . $row['id'] . "'>delete</a></td>";
```

With a external delete.php but it's not working at all... [link](http://s27.postimg.org/cbgz6qo9v/2016_03_02_18_33_00_localhost_8080_localhost.png) in the link the tutorial I used for delete.php

My detail page where the delete button should be in after CV:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "usbw";
$dbname = "persons";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT person_firstname, person_lastname, 
           person_email, person_phonenumber,  
           address_street,address_housenumber, 
           address_city,address_state,address_zipcode, cv_path
    FROM person 
       inner join address on address.address_id = person.person_address 
       inner join cv on cv.cv_id = person.person_cv";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

  echo "<table border=1>
  <tr>
  <th>Voornaam</th>
  <th>Achternaam</th>
  <th>Straat</th>
  <th>Huisnummer</th>
  <th>Postcode</th>
  <th>Stad</th>
  <th>Provincie</th>
  <th>Email</th>
  <th>Mobiel</th>
  <th>CV</th>
  </tr>";


while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["person_firstname"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["person_lastname"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["address_street"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["address_housenumber"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["address_zipcode"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["address_city"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["address_state"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["person_email"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["person_phonenumber"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><a href='http://localhost:8080/website/" . $row['cv_path'] . "'>cv file</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
}
else {
echo "Er is niks in het database gevonden";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Delete.php:

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password="usbw"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="persons"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="person"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// get value of id that sent from address bar 
$id=$_GET['person_id'];

// Delete data in mysql from row that has this id 
$sql="DELETE FROM $tbl_name WHERE person_id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully deleted
if($result){
echo "Deleted Successfully";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='admin.php'>Back to main page</a>";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}
?> 

<?php
// close connection 
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: make life simple - use InnoDB tables and set foreign keys with cascaded deletes ~ that way when you delete a record from one of the primary tables all dependent records from related tables will be deleted

Comment: I guess you have foreign keys which are missing the `on delete` constraint: just alter those keys to `on delete cascade` and all data belonging to a user will be deleted with him

Comment: I agree with RamRaider, cascade delete seems a good solution.  Many databases support that (I use SQL Server) so your database might too.

Comment: I am kinda new to PHP so please explain. I don't want to change anything in my database.

Comment: Take a look at [Adding constraints in phpMyAdmin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499675/adding-constraints-in-phpmyadmin) (and all links in comments there should contain valuable information too)

Comment: Alright I looked at the link and check if my tables are InnoDB they are and also I added ON DELETE Cascade. How do I go further from here... My delete.php is still not working. Ill add delete.php above.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do it:

1. Manually delete from all the 3 tables. Below is the query for that:

   `delete prsn, addr, cv
   from person prsn
   join address addr on p.person_address = addr.address_id
   join cv cv on prsn.person_cv = cv.cv_id
   where prsn.id = ?`
2. Create foreign key constraint in such a way that child record automatically gets deleted once parent record is deleted. E.g. recreate address table like this:

   `create table address(
   ...
   FOREIGN KEY (address_id) 
           REFERENCES person(person_Address)
           ON DELETE CASCADE
   );`

and then, we just need to execute the below query:

`delete from person where id = ?`

Answer (score 2):

I see from the screenshot that you are already using `InnoDB` tables so it should not be too hard to set some foreign key dependencies on the `address` and `cv` tables using `person_id` as the referenced column.

As an example of using Foreign keys to achive the `rippled delete` that seems to be causing issues here are three tables that have a foreign key dependency set - that way you could delete from the `person` table ~ using the `id` of the person and all records from the related tables would also be deleted.

```
create table if not exists `person` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned not null auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(50) not null,
  primary key (`id`)
) engine=innodb auto_increment=2 default charset=latin1;

create table if not exists `address` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned not null auto_increment,
  `person_id` int(10) unsigned not null default '0',
  `address` varchar(50) not null default '0',
  primary key (`id`),
  unique key `person_id` (`person_id`),
  constraint `fk_user_address` foreign key (`person_id`) references `person` (`id`) on delete cascade on update cascade
) engine=innodb auto_increment=2 default charset=latin1;

create table if not exists `cv` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned not null auto_increment,
  `person_id` int(10) unsigned not null default '0',
  `cv` varchar(50) not null default '0',
  primary key (`id`),
  key `person_id` (`person_id`),
  constraint `fk_user_cv` foreign key (`person_id`) references `person` (`id`) on delete cascade on update cascade
) engine=innodb auto_increment=2 default charset=latin1;

/* dummy data */
insert into `person` (`id`, `name`) values (1, 'bobby');
insert into `address` (`id`, `person_id`, `address`) values (1, 1, '99 riverside drive, dundee');
insert into `cv` (`id`, `person_id`, `cv`) values (1, 1, 'bobby_cv.docx');


/* this is how the tables look */    
person table
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | Bobby |
+----+-------+

address table
+----+---------------+----------------------------+
| id | person_id(fk) | address                    |
+----+---------------+----------------------------+
|  1 |         1     | 99 Riverside Drive, Dundee |
+----+---------------+----------------------------+

cv table
+----+---------------+---------------+
| id | person_id(fk) | cv            |
+----+---------------+---------------+
|  1 |         1     | bobby_cv.docx |
+----+---------------+---------------+
```

To delete all records associated with Bobby in this case the sql could simply be:

```
delete from `person` where `id`=1;
```

Without using Foreign keys like this you would need to construct individual sql statements for each table from which you wish to delete the user and his/her associated records.

ie:

```
delete from person where person_id=X;
delete from address where person_id=X;
delete from cv where person_id=X;
```

---

update

Apologies for delay responding - sleep called.

In your sql SELECT statement, used to display the users with associated details from other tables, you do not select the `person_id` which is the key ( pun intended ) element required to make the delete statement work.

```
$sql = "SELECT person_id, person_firstname, person_lastname, 
       person_email, person_phonenumber,  
       address_street,address_housenumber, 
       address_city,address_state,address_zipcode, cv_path
FROM person 
   inner join address on address.address_id = person.person_address 
   inner join cv on cv.cv_id = person.person_cv";
```

So then, in the `while` loop

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $person_id=$row['person_id'];
    /* etc - other content as before */

    /* note the parameter used is "ID" */
    echo "<a href='delete.php?id={$person_id}'>Delete</a>";
}
```

Then in `delete.php` provided the FK dependencies have been set ( and this does all depend how you have done those )

```
/* options used to ensure supplied id is within acceptable bounds */
$options = array(
    'options' => array(
        'default' => 0,
        'min_range' =>  1,
        'max_range' =>  10000000 /* maximum value for ID */
    )
);

/* process GET parameters - notably "ID" */
$id=filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );
$id=(int)filter_var( $id, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $options );

/* construct & execute sql */
if( is_int( $id ) ){
    $sql="delete from `person` where `id`='{$id}';";

    $result=mysql_query( $sql );
}
```

One issue not addressed is that of sql injection. The original code and what I have detailed here both use the now deprecated `mysql_*` family of functions and are susceptible to sql injection. Once you have figured this delete issue it would be prudent to migrate your code to use `mysqli` so that you can utilise `prepared statements`

Comment: There is a relation between those two I think I used an older screenshot but at person_cv it is showing cv_id

Comment: ok - I kinda see the relation in your select statement but not so clear in the screenshot - sorry about that.

Comment: Still not working for me.. How do I edit my delete.php in a way it will delete the all the records?