# How can I prevent duplicate entries over multiple columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
CREATE TABLE `FOLLOWERS` 
(`FOLLOWER_ID` char(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, 
`FOLLOWING_ID` char(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, 
`FOLLOWING_IN` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

How can I prevent duplicate entries over multiple columns?

For example, I don't need anything like this

| FOLLOWER_ID | FOLLOWING_ID | FOLLOWING_IN |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 283 | 283 | ... |
| 193 | 283 | ... |
| 908 | 908 | ... |

- First row = Bad
- Second = Good
- Third = Bad

And I want to ask, Is the followers' table looks good design?

Comment: Many people would expect an ID column to be numeric. The example data you share is consistent with that expectation. It's puzzling that you chose `char` as the type.

Comment: @JeffHolt Yes User Id is Char like this A34zwie29143, But above is example only

Comment: That looks like a user name, not a user id. Would you really want to modify more than one row if a user wanted to use another name?

Comment: I get user id from firebase auth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using MySQL 8.0.16 or newer, you can use a `CHECK` constraint.

```
CREATE TABLE `FOLLOWERS` (
    `FOLLOWER_ID` char(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, 
    `FOLLOWING_ID` char(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, 
    `FOLLOWING_IN` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    CONSTRAINT CHECK (FOLLOWER_ID != FOLLOWING_ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

If you're using an older version, see [Can a MySQL trigger simulate a CHECK constraint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734920/can-a-mysql-trigger-simulate-a-check-constraint) for how to emulate check constraints with triggers.

Comment: a symbol name was expected a reserved keyword can not be used as a column name without backquotes (near CHECK)

Comment: The condition has to be in parentheses.

Comment: Can I add CONSTRAINT CHECK manually in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: I don't use PhpMyAdmin, so I don't know how you do it there.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499675/adding-constraints-in-phpmyadmin

Comment: I used your command but I still can add same value in `FOLLOWER_ID` and `FOLLOWING_ID`, I used this command to again `SHOW CREATE TABLE FOLLOWERS` but the command looks without your edit, Looks like in my question above

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? It's only enforced starting with 8.0.16.

Comment: Less than that, What is the alternative?

Comment: You could write a BEFORE INSERT trigger that checks for it and signals an error.

Comment: Could you leave an example please?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734920/can-a-mysql-trigger-simulate-a-check-constraint for examples