# How can I cancel insertion inside the trigger?

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

Inside the History table, The COL1 shouldn't be like COL2, If was equal then cancel the insertion.

How can I do it?

Comment: Read about `SIGNAL` in the manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/signal.html

Comment: Are you sure you really want to do this in a trigger? Why not create a constraint for that?

Comment: @JonasMetzler Okay, The history table was an example only, The real table is called Followers with two columns, Follower_Id and Following_Id, I don't want to allow the user to follow himself, I make conditions on the client side but I want to increase the safety

Comment: *I don't want allow the user follow himself* Table-level CHECK constraint solves this easily. PS. Common XY-problem..

Comment: Ok, but this is no answer. Why do you want to create a trigger instead of a check constraint? Is there a special reason for that?

Comment: @JonasMetzler Because [Barmar said in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72408295/18753735) that is not possible in MySQL version below 8.0.16, And suggested to use Triggers

Comment: @Akina, Hi Akina, Check the the answer in the link

Comment: Ok, thanks. You didn't tell us before that you're using an older MySQL version ;)

Comment: @Akina Is it possible to do it without triggers?

Comment: @JonasMetzler I tried many ways like unique key index but does not work as I expected, I hope I find a way to do that without triggers or with, Not matter, Thanks

Comment: @BillKarwin Signal works with MySQL 8.0 and above but I have 5.7

Comment: *Is it possible to do it without triggers?* On MySQL 5.7 - no, version 8.0.16 needed.

Comment: @Akina I'm using Bluehost and I don't know if I can update the MySQL version, Anyway do you know how can I cancel the insert according to the condition above?

Comment: SIGNAL has been supported for years. It does not require MySQL 8.0. I only linked to the 8.0 manual because it's the current version.

Comment: @BillKarwin Where can I find SQLSTATE list? Thanks

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-errors/8.0/en/server-error-reference.html but if this is for a user-defined error, just use `'45000'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For MySQL 5.7 use

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER prevent_self_referencing
BEFORE INSERT
ON tablename
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.column1 = NEW.column2 THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Self-referencing not allowed.';
    END IF;
END
```

And the same trigger for `BEFORE UPDATE`.

In shown window insert only 3 code lines, the whole IF statement.

Comment: It's working, I think to BEGIN and END is not required here because that better to add it when we have multiple commands. Could you tell me more about Signal? Is it related to the client side?

Comment: MESSAGE_TEXT is optional?

Comment: @T38416 [SIGNAL Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/signal.html)