# Set up foreign key without InnoDB

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys

I'm wondering if it is possible to use foreign keys for MySQL v.5.0.77 without using InnoDB as database engine. The provider only seems to support MyISAM, Memory, MRG_MYISAM. According to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459312/setting-up-foreign-keys-in-phpmyadmin) I have to use InnoDB.

Comment: Posted thread is correct. Find a new provider.

Comment: InnoDB has been the default DB engine in MySQL for some time now. If your provider does not support the default engine, follow Mike's advice and find someone else.  Makes you wonder what else they don't support.  Maybe they don't run a current version of MySQL?  Maybe they don't provide security updates?

Comment: The other posts are correct, but i want to point out, that you can simulate foreign keys with the help of triggers. But this makes your schema very complex to maintain. I also would suggest to find a different provider which offers InnoDB tables.

Comment: this should be about iPage. you can not get everything just for 1$