# phpmyadmin doesnt allow me to add primary/foreign key relationship

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

That is the primary table field (tasks table):

```
task_id int(10)     UNSIGNED    No  None    AUTO_INCREMENT
```

This is my foreign table field (url_error_stats table):

```
task_id int(10)     UNSIGNED    No  None
```

url_error_stats doesnt present the "relation view" option to connect between the keys..why?

> SQL query:
>
> ALTER TABLE  `url_error_stats` ADD FOREIGN KEY (  `task_id` )
>   REFERENCES  `aws_backlinks`.`tasks` (
>
> `task_id` ) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE ;

MySQL said:

> 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint
>   fails (`aws_backlinks`., CONSTRAINT `#sql-6f0_3bd_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`task_id`) REFERENCES `tasks` (`task_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE
>   CASCADE)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to use innodb and index the primary key if you want to create the foreign keys. and I will recommend you to use NAVICAT . its much easier to create foreign keys and quick too. but for a quick phpmyadmin guide see

[Setting up foreign keys in phpMyAdmin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459312/setting-up-foreign-keys-in-phpmyadmin)

Comment: It works with innodb..but see update on the error that I get..when I connect and use "cascade on delete"

Comment: have you truncate both tables first ?

Comment: I need both empty and then connect ...hmm

Comment: Note that truncating is not needed, see @GarryOne's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Another reason can be the unrelated data in your tables. I mean you may have a foreign key that doesn't exist in parent table.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted as it was the solution to my problem

Answer (score 0):

in this , click on url_error_stats table, then on right hand side it will show all the fields list, so now check on checkbox of that particular field which u wanted to be foreign and click on the link ***relation view*** (which is provided by phpmyadmin below to the table fields with blue color hyperlink).

it will open relationship screen , there You can select the field of the primary table.
Thanks