# phpmyadmin doesnt allow me to add foreign key relationship

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

i tried to add foreign key but cudn't add it. i read several questions regarding this matter. but those options are not works with me. ( [Tried as this way too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6244893/1395178)

My table structure as below

**tab_project**

*column Name*

ProjectID -- > primary key

ProjectName

**tab_project_day**

Primary Key ----> ProjectID + Day

foreign key ----> ProjectID  references ProjectID in tab_project

[image]

**tab_photo**

Primary Key ---->
[image]

i want to create tab_photo foreign keys as follows:

tab_photo.ProjectID --- > reference tab_project_day.ProjectID

tab_photo.Day ------- > reference tab_project_day.day

in here it does not allow me to add tab_photo.Day key.

i tried this one--

```
ALTER TABLE `tab_photo` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`Day`) REFERENCES
`xyz`.`tab_project_day`(`Day`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

it gives below error :

```
#1005 - Can't create table 'xyz.#sql-97c_1c6' (errno: 150)
```

what is the reason for this? please help!!!

Comment: is there any data in tab_project_day ?

Comment: @legendinmaking yes... in tab_project_day has data. but no data in tab_photo? is that can be reason?

Comment: there should be no value in tab_photo.Day which is not present in tab_project_day.Day

Comment: @legendinmaking i removed all data from tab_project_day table too.. but still it doesn't allow me to add foreign key

Comment: and make sure tab_project_day.Day is an index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the collation order of the two tables. I have found that if table A is not the same collation as table B the foreign key can tbe created. Both tables have to be the same collation. Also the columns need to be the same collation.

I suspect this might be your problem. Run the following queries to see the collation

Table Collation:

```
SELECT   TABLE_NAME,
         TABLE_COLLATION
 FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
 WHERE   TABLE_NAME = "tab_project" 
         OR TABLE_NAME="tab_project_day"
```

Column Collation:

```
SELECT       TABLE_NAME
             , COLUMN_NAME
             , COLLATION_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE   TABLE_NAME = "tab_project" 
        OR TABLE_NAME="tab_project_day"
```

Comment: I also hit my head on that one. It was maddening beyond belief as I could not figure it out then I just recreated the tables in a new database and it worked. Took me a while to realise the collations where wrong.