# How to insert values in a new mysql db column without starting a new row?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have two tables in a mysql database: Table Cars and Table Comments. Table cars has columns ID which is auto incremented and name. For each name in table cars I want to have a column in table comments and post the comments from users as they come. How do I insert a new value in an empty column without creating a new row.
Basically what happens is say I have this database

```
X _ _ 
X _ _
X _ _
```

Instead of posting

```
X _ X 
X _ _
X _ _
```

it is inserting the new value at

```
X _ _ 
X _ _
X _ _
_ _ X
```

And then the next one at

```
    X _ _ 
    X _ _
    X _ _
    _ _ X
    _ X _
```

I have looked at the `join` function but that seems to join just two columns and not a row with a column. I've also seen

```
SELECT @row := @row + 1 as row, t.*
FROM some_table t, (SELECT @row := 0) r
```

but it is not explained very well. How do I make this work?

Comment: I think you might be mis-understanding fundamental concepts of databasing. Why would you want it to work like this?

Comment: update how, I know I need to update but how to I get where to update.

Comment: UPDATE Table_Cars SET Comment="This is a commentary" where ID=NUMERIC_ID

Comment: @esqew yes, that's why I am asking, if I knew how it's supposed to be done I wouldn't be here asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your schema, as described, doesn't make any sense. If you want to have multiple `Comment`s per `Car`, add a foreign key on `Comment` to refer to the `Car` it's talking about.

```
Car (Id, Name)
Comment (Id, CarId, CommentText)
```

Then, whenever a `Comment` comes in,

```
INSERT INTO Comment (CarId, CommentText) VALUES (@CarId, @CommentText)
```

Comment: I used this to create the foreign key: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/459312/setting-up-foreign-keys-in-phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to find the row you are selecting and then doing an `update`, instead of doing an `insert`.

You can also achieve this by using a `trigger`. Let me know if this is what you want to do and I will expand on my post.

This page will tell you what `UPDATE` is: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

If the row exists, then do an update, otherwise do an insert. This is a sample code. You have to customize it according to your table names:

```
INSERT INTO CarComment (col1, col2)
VALUES ("value1","value2")
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
  value1=VALUES(something)
```

The explanation of the `VALUES()` is this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_values