# Trying to set a foreign key in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Im trying to set up a foreign key within one of my tables although I don't get the option to select foreign key constraints as shown in the below screenshot. Any idea on how I can go about setting foreign keys?

[image]

Comment: Just to be sure: Are you using an engine that supports foreign keys? InnoDB does, most others don't.

Comment: Have you tried the steps in this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/q/459312/182402

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have both column type the same. without that, it will not show on your dropdown / unable to save

Comment: Yes they are both the same type, i have tried to put this into the SQL although continues to give syntax errors:                                         FOREIGN KEY (user_id) 
REFERENCES users(user_id)
ON DELETE CASCADE

Answer (score 0):

simply go to sql and go with the following query

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name_with_foreignKey`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `foreignKey_constraint_name` 
  FOREIGN KEY (`Column_name_of_foreignkey`) 
  REFERENCES `table_having_referenceTokey`(`column_name_of_primaryKey`) 
  ON DELETE CASCADE 
  ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```