# phpMyAdmin column reference

Tags: database

I`m working with phpMyAdmin database, and I have two tables - "Playlist" and "Songs". At the Playlist table I want to have a column of "Songs in playlist", that will contain a list of the "Songs id" from the "Songs" table. can I do that ?

Comment: Maybe this previous post on Stack Overflow will help you...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/459312/setting-up-foreign-keys-in-phpmyadmin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add a new table that contains a reference to both playlist and songs. That way you have made a many-to-many relation.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29